# Theta-model: In which sense is $S_1$ attracting in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am reading [this wiki about the theta-model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_model).

The model is given by
$$
\frac{d\theta}{dt}=1-\cos\theta+(1+\cos\theta)I(t),\theta\in S^1.
$$

When $I<0$, there are a stable and an unstable equilibria on $S^1$.

It is said that, since $S^1$ is stable in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the unstable equilibrium is actually a saddle-point.

> > The equation above is only defined for $\theta\in S^1$. So I do not understand how $S^1$ can be stable in $\mathbb{R}^2$ when the system is not meant to be defined on whole $\mathbb{R}^2$!

Comment: Maybe they understand the phrase "$S^1$ is stable in $\Bbb R^2$" with respect to some other differential equation, say $dr/dt = ...$, and the solution $r\equiv 1$ is attracting stable.

Comment: Probably yes, but I do not see which differential equation may be meant.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is taken a bit out of context. Reading the wiki page (but I agree it is not very well written) you see in the section before that they discuss a model in the plane in which $\dot{x}=f(x)$ should have a critical point at the origin and the circle should be attracting. Now, the dynamics on the circle is then just one-dimensional and it is the Theta model you mention in the post.

When the dynamics on the circle has an unstable fixed point, then in the plane it is a saddle point since there must be a stable eigendirection transversal to the circle (in the planar model).