# Dynamics of a system near a SNIC bifurcation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Theta-neuron is a one-dimensional neural model that describes the state of the neuron with a phase variable
$$
\theta'=(1-\cos\theta)+(1+\cos\theta)(\beta+\text{ Inputs}(I))\qquad (1)
$$
where $\theta$ is between $0$ and $2\pi$, i.e. $\theta\in S^1=\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$.

The following are quotes from *Theta-Neuron Model* by Boris Gutkin.

> > Theta-neuron is equivalent to the quadratic integrate-and-fire (QIF) neuron or the quadratic normal form for the SNIC bifurcation, making the theta-neuron a canonical model: in a sense all models exhibiting the SNIC bifurcation can be reduced (in a sufficiently local neighborhood of the bifurcation) to the theta-neuron.
> >
> > The theta-neuron is equivalent to the quadratic integrate-and-fire neuron, as it is derived by a change of variable from the quadratic normal form for the SNIC bifurcation.

Next, the following ODE is considered.

> > Let us start with a dynamical equation that describes the dynamics of a system near a SNIC bifurcation. *It can be shown that any system of arbitrary dimension admitting SNIC can be described by a canonical equation on R(1)*:
> >     $$
> > x'(t)=x^2(t)+\beta.\qquad (2)
> > $$
> >     Here, $\beta$ determined if we have two steady states or if the solutions blow up in real time periodically. When $\beta<0$, the two states are stable and unstable points (given by $x=-\sqrt{\beta}, x=\sqrt{\beta}$ respectively). *Note that in the full system the latter corresponds to a saddle point with a one-dimensional unstable manifold that is invariant.

**Questions**

What is meant with $R(1)$? Unfortunately, this is not explained.

Which system is meant to be the full system associated with (2)? I think this is related to [Theta-model: In which sense is $S_1$ attracting in $\mathbb{R}^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1899353/theta-model-in-which-sense-is-s-1-attracting-in-mathbbr2) where I was also wondering what was meant with *full system*.